# Swapping mouse-1 and mouse-2

Tags: emacs, mouse

How can I swap mouse-1 and mouse-2 on Emacs?  There must be a simple .emacs code; I spent one hour searching on the web but I couldn't find any example...  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you only want to swap these buttons for Emacs? Normally I swap them at the OS level when I'm working left-handed so that all applications are affected.

Comment: I just want to swap these for Emacs only.  Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with

```
(define-key input-decode-map [mouse-1] [mouse-2])
(define-key input-decode-map [down-mouse-1] [down-mouse-2])
(define-key input-decode-map [mouse-2] [mouse-1])
(define-key input-decode-map [down-mouse-2] [down-mouse-1])
...
```

But if you tell us why, maybe we can give a better answer.  E.g. you might want to take a look at `mouse-1-click-follows-link` which performs a similar (but partial) swap (and is activated by default).

Comment: Hi Stefan: Thanks so much for your help.  I want to swap the click buttons because my mouse-2 is 'disabled.'  I am running Emacs on a Thinkpad and the button is actually assigned to vertical scroll.  But I need the mouse-2 to list the correct spelling on Flyspell.  Do you think that there would be a better way to address the issue?